# How to convert this Bash script to PowerShell

Tags: bash, azure, powershell, terraform, jq

In Terraform I want to check if a resource group already exists or not. Currently I am using a Bash script to check this but this obviously won't work on Windows. My plan is to convert this script to ps1.

I have little to no experience with PowerShell so I have no clue how to convert it to ps1.

This is the Bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash 

eval "$(jq -r '@sh "GROUP_NAME=\(.group_name)"')"
result=$(az group exists -n $GROUP_NAME)

jq -n --arg exists "$result" '{"exists":$exists}'
```

How can I make a start on this?

Comment: Do you have `jq` available in PowerShell?

Comment: I do not, is it only possible with jq?

Comment: No, but since the bash script is pretty centered around `jq` it'll require a total rewrite. Perhaps it'll be better if you instead focus the question around what the current script actually does and how to implement that in PowerShell. Btw, does it _have_ to be in PowerShell? If you install WSL2 + one of the linux dists + jq + azure-cli on your Windows machine, you can run the script without making any changes to it.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be in powershell, it just has to work on windows and the user can't do any complex installations, since jq is pretty easy, I am allowed to use that too. I would learn powershell if I could but I'm on a time crunch and don't have time for that right now sadly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the PowerShell equivalent of your `bash` script, using only native PowerShell features; place the code in a `.ps1` file, say `foo.ps1`, and pipe the JSON input of interest to it; e.g.:
`'{ "group_name": "foo" }' | .\foo.ps1`

```sh
# Extract the .group_name property value from the JSON input
# provided via the pipeline and save it in variable $GROUP_NAME
$GROUP_NAME = ($Input | ConvertFrom-Json).group_name

# Call the Azure CLI with the group name as the argument.
$result = az group exists -n $GROUP_NAME

# Construct a hashtable with an 'exists' entry that contains the
# result obtained from Azure and convert it to pretty-printed JSON
# (use -Compress to get single-line, non-pretty-printed output).
# Note: Unlike jq's output, the text will *not* be colored (syntax-highlighted).
@{ exists = $result } | ConvertTo-Json
```